# Testflight build not getting in iPhone TestFlight app for test

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

In Apple Connect --> TestFlight app is showing and email id is showing correctly for old app build number but app not listed in Testflight mobile app for testing

Note:  I have removed and add the same email id not received any mail

I had tried - remove email from tester and re-add the same email id not receive any mail from apple for new build for that mail id

Comment: It might be useful for you to attach some screenshots of your appstoreconnect screens

Comment: You won't receive additional invitations for the same email. The app is associated with the Apple ID that is signed into the App Store when you redeem the invitation, not the email that it was sent to. Perhaps the invitation was redeemed by a different Apple ID than is currently signed in on your device?

Comment: for example I have 3 app in App Store connect TestFlight in that I only have 2 app in TestFlight app but I have invited for 3 apps.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the releases of your app in App Store Connect. There might be a compliance question you need to answer before each build can be released to TestFlight testers.

Comment: for others they can see and they receive once new build update only for my mail id its not showing app and not getting mail for new update